# Calling a static/shared method from a non-static/shared methd, good or bad?

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop, class-design

Let's say for instance I have a class set up as such:

```
Class Foo
    Private instanceVariable As Integer = 2

    Public Shared Function Bar(ByVal localVariable as Integer) As Integer
        Return localVariable * 2
    End Function

    Public Function Bar() As Integer
        Return Bar(instanceVariable)
    End Function
End Class
```

I have a, hopefully, relatively simple question/s. Is this good design or is this frowned upon? Why?

EDIT:
After some of the comments I'm refining what I'm asking.

Is this *inherently* bad? Or is it perfectly fine, but as with everything it can be misused?

Comment: Calling `Math.Pow` is good or bad?

Comment: I'm not asking if calling/creating static methods is good or bad, I know that they are necessary and definitely are good. I'm just curious if this design in particular is bad, where you are just calling a static method from a non-static method and just passing in the instance variables.

Comment: I think the main problem here is that @Crono has got it right, it depends, the rest is up to opinion, and opinion-based answers (or rather, questions that need opinionated answers) are not really all that constructive here on Stack Overflow. The main question is this: *what do you think*?

Comment: Ya...I was afraid it may be a little borderline...I can see ups to it, I guess my main question was "Is this bad to do for some reason?" Honestly, just wasn't sure if there was any overhead or possible issues that could arise from this.

Comment: I think asking if shared methods on non shared classes are bad or not hardly leaves place for opinions. In itself, the practice is *not* bad. As a testimony to that it is widespread deep within the framework itself. The "it depends" part really comes with what the intention is, which isn't quite the point here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In itself, the practice is **not bad**. It's the code's intention that will determine whether or not your design choice is appropriate. When you think about it, that applies to pretty much every known coding patterns. You might as well have asked if using generic types or multithreading are good practices or not, the answer would've been the same.

There are non-static classes within the .NET framework that does use shared methods and within their own context it makes perfect sense. This alone should allow you to think it's not a bad practice at all.

All you have to do is simply questioning yourself about what you are trying to do and if whether it makes sense or not to do it in a static context.

Comment: Fixed so it's more clear what's going on. In regards to your answer though, so it's not really a bad practice or anything? I guess that's kinda the main question: "Is it bad?"

Comment: @JoshBraun see my edited answer. In itself, it isn't bad no. But like anything else it can be used in the wrong way. ;)

Comment: Okay, that answers it basically I think then. Thanks, Crono.